# How to remove/hide tabbar in tabbarconmtroller app?

Tags: objective-c

In my tabbarcontroller application having four bars, each tabbar having navigationcontroller inside viewcontroller. How should i hide for particular tabbar for particular tab in landscape orientation?.

Comment: I have *no* idea what you are trying to do. Please edit your question to be more clear.

Answer (score 2):

To hide the TabBar when you push a new viewController to the navigation stack, simply add this code to the init method of that viewController:

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```